# why j(for) loop is not working here?

Tags: java

If I write

```
if(y.charAt(i)==y.charAt(i+1))
```

then `deleteCharAt()` works but if I take a j i.e.

```
 if(y.charAt(i)==y.charAt(j))
```

then it doesn't works why ?

Try it: http://ideone.com/WBtYDA

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int t = s.nextInt();
t++;
while (t-- > 0) {
    String r = s.next();
    StringBuffer y = new StringBuffer(r);
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i <= r.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= r.length(); j++)
                if (y.charAt(i) == y.charAt(j)) {
                    y.deleteCharAt(i);
                }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    System.out.println(y);
}
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do? Input? Output?

Comment: seems straightforward, try paper & pencil to dig through

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code. The second for loop does not have {}.

Comment: @alexvii That is not a syntax error in Java.

Comment: What happens to `y.charAt(10)` if you say `y.deleteCharAt(5)`?  Think about it ...

Comment: I thought it would just work, if the inner block only contains one line.

Comment: input: mississippi    output :misp

Comment: @alexvii The inner block contains one *statement* (the `if`, complete with its own block in `{ }`, is one statement).  Java syntax doesn't care about "lines".

Comment: the code is working perfect for i+1 instead of j.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, never catch and ignore an exception. Either handle it, rethrow it, or wrap it. If you don't think it should happen, just wrap it in a `RuntimeException`.

```
} catch(Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

There was an exception being thrown in your code that you didn't see because of this.
The two checks in the for loops are wrong.

```
i <= r.length()
j <= r.length()
```

should be

```
i < y.length()
j < y.length()
```

This is because `length()` is never a valid index (`length() - 1` is the last valid index), and because `y` can be shorter than `r`, because things could be removed.

Finally, you may want to think about which character your are removing, why you are removing that character, and how the indexes of all of the characters shift once you have removed it.

Comment: ok, but for input: mississippi , my output is coming: missp
instead of misp.

Comment: I assume you are now calling y.deleteCharAt(j) to get that output. After you delete the character at an index, a new character shifts into that index. Do you want to move on to the next index, or do you need to go back and check the same index again?

Comment: check for same index.

Comment: If j is being incremented every time thought the loop, what do you need to do to it so you check the same index again?

Comment: decrement inside loop by 1. Thanks!!